# What does invariant to affine transformations mean?

Tags: affine-geometry, median, invariance

I am researching multivariate medians. In one of my sources it is stated that "Liu showed that the simplicial median is invariant to affine transformations". I am a bit confused about what this means. I know that affine transformations preserve ratios of distances, collinearity but not necessarily angles or lengths. However, I don't know what it means for something to be invariant to affine transformations. Does it mean that it will always remain the same? Also I was wondering if there is a simple example to illustrate this to help improve my understanding.

Comment: As long as I'm aware an affine transformation is a map $ax+b$ for $a\not = 0$ in 1 dimension or $Ax+b$ for an invertible matrix $n$ in general. As I read in https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/books/meg/meg_ch12.pdf bottom of page 9, it seems that a property is invariant under affine maps, if whenever the image of a function $f$ satisfy the property implies that the image of $f\circ\varphi$ satisfy the property for every affine map $\varphi$

Comment: It means that if you apply an affine transformation to the data, the median of the transformed data is the same as the affine transformation applied to the median of the original data. For example, if you rotate the data the median also gets rotated in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Affine transformation are a combination of a translation with a linear transformation

$$A(v)=Av+v_0$$

which preserves points, straight lines and planes.

Ratio by segments are preserved and in particular mean points are preserved by linearity

indeed if $$M=\frac{P+Q}{2}\implies A(M)=\frac{A(P)+A(Q)}{2}+v_0$$

[Affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_geometry#Affine_transformations)